# The request run in while loop controller on Jmeter captured in report

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to generate a test report for a thread group.
I see that since i run a http request in while loop controller, the request shows up in the report with too many failures as i also have an assertion to the request.
These are not failures but, tries, how do i make sure that these dont get captured in the report.
I am using View results in table listener for report. I tried to remove assertion for this http request so that it is not captured in the report? Is this the right approach?

Comment: fix your assertion

Comment: Hi I recommend you to read "[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" and you should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). With that, some user could help you better.

Answer (score 0):

As per [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article:

> 7. Use Assertions Sparingly
>
> Every test element added to the test plan will be processed - and this takes CPU time and memory. This also applies to all your Assertions, and is especially true for Compare Assertions -  which consumes a lot of resources and memory. **Only use the assertions you need and, even then, just use the amount that are absolutely required.**

So removing the assertion seems to be a right approach to me.

Also if it's a [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) you can modify it to accept 2 (or more) criteria so you can configure it to not to fail on "tries", example setup which accepts HTTP Status Codes `200` and `501` and will fail for everything else:

[image]